# Using mobx-model in the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mobx

I am using Mobx and mobx-model for state management in my React app. I am not doing server-side render as of now. But, I have a scenario where I need to use my model in the server side.

An example model in my project is shown below.

```
import { API, BaseModel } from "mobx-model";

class UserModel extends BaseModel {
   ...
   static loadAll() {
     ...
   }
}
```

The above model works fine in the client (in the browser). But, I have a scenario where I need to call the loadAll method from the server.

If I require this model from the server side as follows, I get an error.

```
const { UserModel } = require("../../src/models/models");
```

The error message is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Any idea how I can fix this to work on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. Instead of requiring the UserModel, I could require the API from mobx-model as follows:

```
const { API } = require("mobx-model");
```

I could use the API from the server without much code changes. I have to rewrite a little bit of loadAll logic again in the server. That works for me for now.